# NSLineBreakByCharWrapping not working in iOS7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uilabel, ios8, word-wrap

I have added simple label on a view with numberOfLines = 0 but character wrapping is not working as expected in iOS7. Its always using word wrapping for character wrapping. However I tested the same code in Xcode 6 GM and its working fine.

Is there any other way to handle character wrapping in iOS7 ? This was a known issue in 7 ?

- ios7 charwrapping Attachment:

[image: ios7_charwrapping]

- ios8 charwrapping Attachment:
  [image: ios8_charwrapping]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bug in iOS 7. We have a couple of apps where we accidentally used NSLineBreakCharWrapping, and it just did word wrapping which was what we intended... and they are all of a sudden broken on iOS 8.. it wasn't fixed until iOS 8 probably most of the time wrap by word is used and nobody realized it.

Comment: I agree with you.. i feel the same

Comment: I have the solution, if your using storyboard go add the empty space and change the Text Field plain to Attribute mode and the change the word wrap to character wrapping it will work

Answer (score 0):

Just expanding upon the accepted answer, char wrapping behavior was probably a bug in iOS 7 that did the same thing as word wrapping.  iOS 8 gives it back it's intended behavior and so breaks the use as word wrapping.  So change

```
someLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
```

To word wrapping in iOS 8

```
someLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```